# fetch=FetchType.LAZY causes transaction timeout

Tags: java, spring, jpa, transactions

In one part of my web app i have 4 entities that are linked in a chain by  Arraylists, they are annotaded with `@OneToMany` and the fetchtype is default which is `fetch=FetchType.LAZY`.

My problem is that it takes to long to get all those entities that are linked in the chain, According to Spring they must be retrived in a transaction, thats fine but it takes to long so it will result in 
a transaction rollback, the transaction timeout is set to 5 min and it is deployed o websphere. the guys that are in charge of websphere do not want to raise the transaction timeout due to other applications on the server and unnecessary use 
of resources, also they dont know what effect it will have on other applications if raised. How can i solve this ?

Comment: They have to be retrieved with an active session, which is something different then a transaction. But if it takes too long you might be simply loading to much data into memory, are you sure you need everything.

Comment: i need all entities in the chain, but not all  the values that each entity has. Since the first object i need is a query to the db and i use Spring, it must be inside an transaction which also in this case includes a session.